# TYPO3 routeEnhancer for custom paginate extension

Tags: routes, typo3

We did a custom extension for paginating because we have external data source. This results in a url like [https://domain.ch/de/ourcontent/?tx_vendordspace_vendordspace[@widget_0][currentPage]=3&cHash=e2126ef5f67e3d7539440487d0eda3c9](https://domain.ch/de/ourcontent/?tx_vendordspace_vendordspace%5B@widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=3&cHash=e2126ef5f67e3d7539440487d0eda3c9)

Following config does nothing:

```
routeEnhancers:
  VendorDspace:
    type: Extbase
    extension: VendorDspace
    plugin: VendorDspace
    routes:
      routePath: '/dspace-page/{page}'
        _controller: 'Publication::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
```

Any ideas or tipps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add a - routePath: '/' and defaultController: 'Publication::list'. A colleague found the bug. See full config:

```
routeEnhancers:
  VendorDspace:
    type: Extbase
    extension: VendorDspace
    plugin: VendorDspace
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'Publication::list'
      - routePath: '/dspace-page/{page}'
        _controller: 'Publication::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
    defaultController: 'Publication::list'
    defaults:
      page: '0'
    aspects:
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '100'
```

Answer (score 1):

compared to my configurations you have a wrong indention.

try:

```yaml
    routes:
      routePath: '/dspace-page/{page}'
      _controller: 'Publication::list'
      _arguments:
        page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
```

as I have multiple routes an intermediate level is necessary for you too:

```yaml
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/dspace-page/{page}'
        _controller: 'Publication::list'
        _arguments:
          page: '@widget_0/currentPage'
```

Comment: I removed a '-' while copy it here but these does not solve the problem. I have to add a - routePath: '/' and defaultController: 'Publication::list'. See me answer